# how to identify the request come from which device?

Tags: http, mobile

I need to know about how to know the request comes from which device whether it comes from mobile device or it comes from desktop browsers. And How can I redirect from server to appropriate page(for eg. if it comes from mobile means i have to redirect mobile.html page). Can any help me to do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check [User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent) http header